# Union a List of Flume Receivers in Spark Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

In order to increase parallelism as recommended in the Spark Streaming Programming guide I'm setting up multiple receivers and trying to union a list of them. This code works as expected:

```
    private JavaDStream<SparkFlumeEvent> getEventsWorking(JavaStreamingContext jssc, List<String> hosts, List<String> ports) {

        List<JavaReceiverInputDStream<SparkFlumeEvent>> receivers = new ArrayList<>();

        for (String host : hosts) {
            for (String port : ports) {
                receivers.add(FlumeUtils.createStream(jssc, host, Integer.parseInt(port)));
            }
        }

        JavaDStream<SparkFlumeEvent> unionStreams = receivers.get(0)
                .union(receivers.get(1))
                .union(receivers.get(2))
                .union(receivers.get(3))
                .union(receivers.get(4))
                .union(receivers.get(5));

        return unionStreams;
    }
```

But I don't actually know how many receivers my cluster will have until runtime. When I try to do this in a loop I get an NPE.

```
 private JavaDStream<SparkFlumeEvent> getEventsNotWorking(JavaStreamingContext jssc, List<String> hosts, List<String> ports) {

        List<JavaReceiverInputDStream<SparkFlumeEvent>> receivers = new ArrayList<>();

        for (String host : hosts) {
            for (String port : ports) {
                receivers.add(FlumeUtils.createStream(jssc, host, Integer.parseInt(port)));
            }
        }

        JavaDStream<SparkFlumeEvent> unionStreams = null;
        for (JavaReceiverInputDStream<SparkFlumeEvent> receiver : receivers) {
            if (unionStreams == null) {
                unionStreams = receiver;
            } else {
                unionStreams.union(receiver);
            }
        }

        return unionStreams;
    }
```

ERROR:

> 16/09/15 17:05:25 ERROR JobScheduler: Error in job generator
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph$$anonfun$getMaxInputStreamRememberDuration$2.apply(DStreamGraph.scala:172)
>           at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph$$anonfun$getMaxInputStreamRememberDuration$2.apply(DStreamGraph.scala:172)
>           at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$maxBy$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:225)
>           at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foldl(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:51)
>           at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.reduceLeft(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:68)
>           at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.reduceLeft(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
>           at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.maxBy(TraversableOnce.scala:225)
>           at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.maxBy(Traversable.scala:105)
>           at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph.getMaxInputStreamRememberDuration(DStreamGraph.scala:172)
>           at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator.clearMetadata(JobGenerator.scala:270)
>           at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator.org$apache$spark$streaming$scheduler$JobGenerator$$processEvent(JobGenerator.scala:182)
>           at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anon$1.onReceive(JobGenerator.scala:87)
>           at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anon$1.onReceive(JobGenerator.scala:86)
>           at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
>   16/09/15 17:05:25 INFO MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(15128) called with
>   curMem=520144, maxMem=555755765 16/09/15 17:05:25 INFO MemoryStore:
>   Block broadcast_24 stored as values in memory (estimated size 14.8 KB,
>   free 529.5 MB) Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph$$anonfun$getMaxInputStreamRememberDuration$2.apply(DStreamGraph.scala:172)
>           at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph$$anonfun$getMaxInputStreamRememberDuration$2.apply(DStreamGraph.scala:172)
>           at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$maxBy$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:225)
>           at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foldl(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:51)
>           at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.reduceLeft(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:68)
>           at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.reduceLeft(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
>           at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.maxBy(TraversableOnce.scala:225)
>           at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.maxBy(Traversable.scala:105)
>           at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph.getMaxInputStreamRememberDuration(DStreamGraph.scala:172)
>           at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator.clearMetadata(JobGenerator.scala:270)
>           at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator.org$apache$spark$streaming$scheduler$JobGenerator$$processEvent(JobGenerator.scala:182)
>           at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anon$1.onReceive(JobGenerator.scala:87)
>           at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anon$1.onReceive(JobGenerator.scala:86)
>           at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)

What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: I've also tried JavaDStream<SparkFlumeEvent> unionStreams = jssc.union(receivers.get(0), receivers.subList(1, receivers.size())); but that doesn't compile. Error:(118, 57) java: no suitable method found for union(...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please try out the below code, It would solve your problem:

```
private JavaDStream<SparkFlumeEvent> getEventsNotWorking(JavaStreamingContext jssc, List<String> hosts, List<String> ports) {

    List<JavaDStream<SparkFlumeEvent>> receivers = new ArrayList<JavaDStream<SparkFlumeEvent>>();

    for (String host : hosts) {
        for (String port : ports) {
            receivers.add(FlumeUtils.createStream(jssc, host, Integer.parseInt(port)));
        }
    }

    return jssc.union(receivers.get(0), receivers.subList(1, receivers.size()));;
}
```

Comment: Get this error when compiling: "Error:(133, 85) java: unreachable statement. "Intellij complains: "Incompatible equality constraint: SparkFlumeEvent and T"

Comment: Ignore the unreachable statement error, that was due to the ;; typo in your code that I didn't notice. But intellij still giving that error. It builds successfully though and seems to work. Any idea why intellij is complaning?

Comment: It was an issue with intellij cache :-/ Very frustrating! Solved by following the comments here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15052772/intellij-show-errors-in-scala-source-files-but-the-project-compiles-successfully. Thanks for the help.