# IntelliJ show errors in scala source files but the (maven) project compiles successfully

Tags: scala, maven, intellij-idea

When I open a maven module with scala code ([link](https://github.com/sanskrit-coders/podcasting)) which compiles and runs fine, I get bad error highlights:

[image]

Code-complete seems broken as well. How to fix this? (I don't want to switch to SBT since I only want this one module in the project to use scala, and I've tried the "Invalidate Caches / Restart" fix suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15052772/intellij-show-errors-in-scala-source-files-but-the-project-compiles-successfully) in vain.)

Comment: The highlighting errors disappeared after updating to Scala plugin Version: 2017.2.7 and also updating the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

It is a known problem in IntelliJ with Scala because of the complex type system of scala.

I mostly use sbt. If I encounter such problem, first I compile it with sbt in the command line, most time wrong error highlights disappear.

If this does not help, clear IntelliJ cash and restart it (File -> Invalidated Caches / Restart).